# Why am I receiving an exception for 'Could not load file': SQLiteStore

Tags: xamarin, azure-mobile-services

I attempted this [tutorial](https://blog.xamarin.com/add-a-backend-to-your-app-in-10-minutes/).

However, I receive an error when executing the following code:

```
client.Initialize(@"https://myservice.azurewebsites.net");
```

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLiteStore, Version=2.0.0.0

However, I do have this referenced in my project:

```
assemblyref://Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLiteStore
```

**Code:**

```
using System;
using AppServiceHelpers;

namespace Temp
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            try
            {
                var client = EasyMobileServiceClient.Create();
                client.Initialize(@"https://myservice.azurewebsites.net");

                client.RegisterTable<TodoItem>();

                client.FinalizeSchema();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**References:**

```
assemblyref://Azure.Mobile.Forms
assemblyref://Azure.Mobile
assemblyref://System.Net.Http.Extensions
assemblyref://System.Net.Http.Primitives
assemblyref://SQLitePCLRaw.core
assemblyref://SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_green
assemblyref://SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2
assemblyref://SQLitePCL
assemblyref://Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile
assemblyref://Newtonsoft.Json
assemblyref://Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.SQLiteStore
assemblyref://Microsoft.CSharp
assemblyref://Microsoft.VisualBasic
assemblyref://mscorlib
assemblyref://System.Collections.Concurrent
assemblyref://System.Collections
assemblyref://System.ComponentModel
assemblyref://System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync
assemblyref://System.Core
assemblyref://System.Diagnostics.Contracts
assemblyref://System.Diagnostics.Debug
assemblyref://System.Diagnostics.Tools
assemblyref://System.Diagnostics.Tracing
assemblyref://System
assemblyref://System.Dynamic.Runtime
assemblyref://System.Globalization
assemblyref://System.IO.Compression
assemblyref://System.IO
assemblyref://System.Linq
assemblyref://System.Linq.Expressions
assemblyref://System.Linq.Parallel
assemblyref://System.Linq.Queryable
assemblyref://System.Netassemblyref://System.Net.Http
assemblyref://System.Net.NetworkInformation
assemblyref://System.Net.Primitives
assemblyref://System.Net.Requests
assemblyref://System.Numerics
assemblyref://System.ObjectModel
assemblyref://System.Reflection
assemblyref://System.Reflection.Extensions
assemblyref://System.Reflection.Primitives
assemblyref://System.Resources.ResourceManager
assemblyref://System.Runtime
assemblyref://System.Runtime.Extensions
assemblyref://System.Runtime.InteropServices
assemblyref://System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime
assemblyref://System.Runtime.Numerics
assemblyref://System.Runtime.Serialization
assemblyref://System.Runtime.Serialization.Json
assemblyref://System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives
assemblyref://System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml
assemblyref://System.Security.Principal
assemblyref://System.ServiceModel.Web
assemblyref://System.Text.Encoding
assemblyref://System.Text.Encoding.Extensions
assemblyref://System.Text.RegularExpressions
assemblyref://System.Threading
assemblyref://System.Threading.Tasks
assemblyref://System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel
assemblyref://System.Windows
assemblyref://System.Xml
assemblyref://System.Xml.Linq
assemblyref://System.Xml.ReaderWriter
assemblyref://System.Xml.Serialization
assemblyref://System.Xml.XDocument
assemblyref://System.Xml.XmlSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Mobile Apps SDK requires the use of https, not http.  Change the URL to be a secure connection.

Comment: Thanks for that observation. However, I am still receiving the same error after updating the URL based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

https://myservice.azurewebsites.net may not be the correct URL; confirm the name of the Azure App Service URL is correct - in your Azure Portal;

Comment: Thanks. I hid the actual URL on purpose. I don't believe the exception that I identified is URL related though. Hence, the exception is DLL related.

Answer (score 0):

I was originally using a test project as the client to my azure logic.

**To resolve my issue, I performed the following:**

1. Added an executable project to my solution and threw the code in there.
2. Ensured that my executable was set to x86 processor.
3. Added the SQLite3 DLL to my executable project and set the *build action* to *"content"* and the copy to output directory to *"Copy Always"*.

After I performed the steps above, the code just worked.